# Sessions ignored

Tags: php, session, redirect

I'm trying to create a small language switch script in PHP that is based on sessions. For some reason the session conditional doesn't pass, it is as if every session I try checking for is already set. Am I missing something?

```
<?php
    session_start();
        echo 'session started';
        if ( !isset($_SESSION[ 'language' ]) && empty($_SESSION[ 'language' ]) ) {
          echo 'set new session'; // Never reach this point, it seems the browser already has the session in store. Tried changing the session name several times.
          redirect();
          $_SESSION[ 'language' ] = true;
        }
        function redirect() {
          echo 'running redirect()';
          $language = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );
          switch( $language[0] ) {
            case 'de-DE':
            case 'sv-SE':
            case 'no-NO':
            case 'dk-DK':
              header( 'Location: http://sample.com/' . substr($lang, 0, -3) . '/' );
            break;
          }
        }
?>
```

Comment: you can not output anything before header

Comment: and your code will never reach to `$_SESSION[ 'language' ] = true;` line because you are redirecting before it

Comment: Your snippet is working for me. Have you tried checking this in an incognito window? You might just already have an active session.

Comment: NullPoiиteя Oh, right! Thanks for pointing that out. I believe I got it to work by just changing the order of the function and the session setting.